# simple issue database connecting using oop

Tags: php, mysql, oop

This is dbconnect.class.php:

```
<?php  

class Connect 
{ 
    public $error; 
    protected $db; 
    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","1") or $this->error = mysql_error(); 
        $db = mysql_select_db("tarih",$link); 
        $this->db = $db; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

And this is main php file:

```
<?php
//header.class.php 
require_once 'dbconnect.class.php'; 

class Header extends Connect 
{ 
    public $headers = array(); 
    private $baglan; 
    public function __construct() 
    { 
        /* 
        * Bu sınıf sayfaların header bilgilerini işler. 
        */ 
        $baglan = $this->db; 
    } 

    public function sayfaHeader($sayfa = true) 
    { 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM header WHERE id='" . $sayfa . "'"; 
        $query = mysql_query($sql,$this->baglan); 
    } 


} 

Header::sayfaHeader(); 
?>
```

When I run main php file I see this error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\header.class.php on line 19
```

Line 19:

```
$query = mysql_query($sql,$this->baglan);
```

Where is the problem? I can't see problem becuase I'm not writing php code for so long.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @Truth this is not problem for mysql_ this problem for object-oridient-programming

Comment: I never said it would solve your problem. If I did thought so, I would have posted it as an answer. I'm just saying you should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Header::sayfaHeader();
```

It calls method without object creation. You have to do this

```
Header obj = new Header();
obj->sayfaHeader();
```

If you want to call class's method then declare method as `static`. But you cant use `$this` reference because static methods and memebers haven't reference on class object. 
**UPDATE:** 
`mysql_select_db` returns `bool` value. You have to use your `$link` variable for querying.

Comment: First question: Why? In a sense, i can't use other method?
Second question: now I see this error: Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\header.class.php on line 20

Comment: Non-static method is property of Object. Static method belongs to class not for class instance.

Comment: I answered in my answer under Update

Comment: Yes mysql_select_db returns 1. What need mysql_select-db return?

Comment: You must use $link variable - MySql-link

Comment: Why returns bool? have you got any idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10810/discussion-between-birlikisgu-and-denis-ermolin)

Answer (score 1):

You are not having database issue,

your code is wrong.

```
Header::sayfaHeader();
```

That is for static methods. but you need an instance to call that method actually.

try:

```
Header obj = new Header();
obj->sayfaHeader();
```

Comment: question: now I see this error: Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class

Comment: You are using java in my opinion :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to construct the parent to instantiate the database class

```
public function __construct() 
{ 
    parent::__construct();
    $baglan = $this->db; 
}
```

Comment: Now I can see only: Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\AppServ\www\ilk\class\header.class.php on line 20

Answer (score -1):

```
public function __construct() 
{ 
    // if you do this, add a $this-> to baglan to acces it in the class
    $this->baglan = $this->db; 
} 

public function sayfaHeader($sayfa = true) 
{ 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM header WHERE id='" . $sayfa . "'"; 

    // or, since you inherit the $this->db
    $query = mysql_query($sql,$this->db); 
}
```